# Spark executors require driver memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory, driver

I have 2 spark application. The first read csv files then translates it to parquet (simple read - filter - write). The second reads the parquet files, computes statistics then writes the result to csv files. I had to allocate more driver memory to make them run, otherwise it crashes to a out of memory error.

I noticed that when I reduce the executors and cores to 1 and 1, I don't have to give more driver memory. This looks like managing multiple executors (in my case, I have 10 executors with 5 cores) requires driver memory. If I set up 10 executors with 1 core, or 1 executor with 5 cores, this will crash for example during parquet reading.

What is the correct explanation?

Comment: Are you doing any collect operation on your driver?

Comment: No, in both applications I only manipulate dataframes and write the results to hdfs files.

Comment: After thinking about it, it looks like the driver keeps something from past executors or executions. As soon as there is a lot of work done in executors, it crashes. Is there such a configuration?

Comment: Can you check in the Spark UI and find out which stage is failing ? This would give you some insight on your job and in turn you might have a more specific question to ask us

Comment: This may fail during the parquet job, which is simply spark.read.parquet(sourcePath).where(
      col("mytime") >= startMillis && col("mytime") <= stopMillis)